# Google Glass Quickstart for GO Errors

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-glass, google-api-go-client

When building the GO quickstart for the Google Glass mirror API I am getting the following error.  Has anyone been able to resolve this?

`attachment.go:21: can't find import: "code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/mirror/v1"`

**Update to show relavant entries from .bashrc:**

```
export PATH=$HOME/go_appengine:$PATH
export GOPATH=$HOME/go:$GOPATH
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your console, run `go get code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/mirror/v1` and try again. Make sure you have `$GOPATH` set before.

Comment: Do you mean ensure I have the lines in the update above in my .bashrc?    For the command I get go command not found.

Comment: you don't have $GOROOT set. it should be where you put the actual Go sdk (/usr/local/go in my case)

Comment: Don't set $GOROOT. That's not necessary. For Go on App Engine use 'goapp get' instead of 'go get'.

Comment: Using goapp get for each of the missing dependencies solved the problem.

Comment: @RussCox  good to know, I've never worked with Go on AppEngine and didn't know it's a different toolchain.